# Primefaces dataTable cannot edit after tab changed

Tags: primefaces, datatable, tabview

Originally I used an editable dataTable, and it worked fine.
Then I put the dataTable in a dymanic tabView's tabs, then in the first rendered tab workes fine, but after I change tab, I cannot edit cells.
PrimeFaces version: 6.0

```
<p:tabView value="#{tippingViewBean.rounds}" var="round" dynamic="true">

    <p:tab title="#{round}.">

        <p:dataTable id="tippingTable#{round}" rowIndexVar="rowId" editable="true" editMode="cell"
                     widgetVar="cellTips"
                     var="userTip" value="#{tippingViewBean.getUserTips(round)}"
                     resizableColumns="true">

            <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{tippingViewBean.addTip(userTip)}"/>

            <p:column headerText="Kezdés">
                <h:outputText value="#{userTip.schedule.date}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Hazai Csapat">
                <h:outputText value="#{userTip.schedule.homeTeam.name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Vendég Cspat">
                <h:outputText value="#{userTip.schedule.awayTeam.name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Győztes">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{userTip.winnerTip}"/></f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="winnerTipInput#{round}"
                                         disabled="#{tippingViewBean.tipIsClosed(userTip)}"
                                         value="#{tippingViewBean.winnerTip}" style="width: 100%">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{tippingViewBean.winnerTipForSelection}" var="selectItem"
                                           itemLabel="#{selectItem}" itemValue="#{selectItem}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="2,5 Gól alatt/felett">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{userTip.twoAndHalfTip}"/></f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="goalsTipInput#{round}"
                                         disabled="#{tippingViewBean.tipIsClosed(userTip)}"
                                         value="#{tippingViewBean.goalsTip}" style="width: 100%">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{tippingViewBean.goalsTipForSelection}" var="goalsSelectItem"
                                           itemLabel="#{goalsSelectItem}" itemValue="#{goalsSelectItem}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>

    </p:tab>

</p:tabView>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer.
I changed the dataTable's widgetVar to unique ( cellTips#{round} ), and it works.